# Is-it possible to customize the template of preview in django import-export?

Tags: django, import, django-import-export

My admin side will be used by no-sys-admin persons so I would like it to be as clear as possible. I don't understand how can I customize the preview before confirming import.

To add objects with foreign key reference I juste look for id that matches in `before_import` function and replace it as it's explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697797/dealing-with-import-of-foreignkeys-in-django-import-export/29071070#29071070).

If you modify the dataset in before_import function, it doesn't spread to the preview, preview only display the object of my model class, nothing more...

How can I display the name of the family (column `Famille`) in my exemple ?
[image]

My model :

```
class TGenres(models.Model):
    id_genre = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    nom_genre = models.CharField(max_length=1024,verbose_name='nom de genre')
    id_fam = models.ForeignKey(TFamilles, null=True, db_column='id_fam', blank=True, verbose_name='Famille')
```